# What the notation $A\triangle B$ means?

Tags: general-topology, notation

Reading some notes on point-set topology I saw the notation $A\triangle B$ in one exercise, without any explanation of what the notation means. In this case $A$ and $B$ are sets. To provide the full context, the exercise was:

> Let $X$ be a finite set, show that
>
> $$d(A,B)= \# A\triangle B$$
>
> is a metric.

In that case, is the notation $A\triangle B$ somehow standard? If it is, what this notation means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\Delta B$ is the symmetric difference of the sets $A$ and $B$, the set of elements that are in exactly one of $A$ and $B$. It is also equal to $(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$.

So $\#(A\Delta B)$ is the cardinality of the set $A\Delta B$, since the ground set is finite, this is just an integer.

Answer (score 2):

$A\Delta B = (A \cap \bar{B}) \cup (\bar{A} \cap B)$

edit: Which is the same as CoS answer, but written differently.

Comment: what is $\overline B$ ? Is it  the complement of $B$?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Yes.

Answer (score 2):

[image: symmetric difference $A \triangle B$]
The picture depicts the "symmetric difference $A \triangle B$" of two set A and B.